# Angular, how to include multiple components in a lazy loaded module?

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

On my homepage I have 4 links to components that all belong to a feature module called 'CrudModule'.

I'm wondering how to lazy load this module, this doesn't seem to work :

**my app-routing.module.ts:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'add', loadChildren: () => import(`./crudFeatureModule/crud.module`).then(x => x.CrudModule) }
  , { path: 'search', loadChildren: () => import(`./crudFeatureModule/crud.module`).then(x => x.CrudModule) }
  , { path: 'importer', loadChildren: () => import(`./crudFeatureModule/crud.module`).then(x => x.CrudModule) }
  , { path: 'publier', loadChildren: () => import(`./crudFeatureModule/crud.module`).then(x => x.CrudModule) }
];
```

In the official Angular docs only one component per module is mentioned, see
this example from https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules :

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(mod => mod.CustomersModule)
  },
```

**customers-routing.module.ts:**

```
  import { CustomerListComponent } from './customer-list/customer-list.component';
  
  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CustomerListComponent
  }
];
```

The above path is set to an empty string. This is because the path in AppRoutingModule is already set to 'customers'.

Question : given that the path of a lazy loaded module always needs to be empty, does this mean that I should put all my components in different modules in order to implement lazy loading? In other words can a lazy loaded module handle multiple routes ?
If so, how should I go about it?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what exactly is happening?

Generally speaking, you'd have one parent route which lazily loads the child module, and that child module will have its own internal routing. You can have as many components as you like in one module.

Comment: the question seems unclear, can you be more specific

Comment: It's not working because my feature module only recognizes an empty path : the route that the user clicked on. What I mean is that a lazy loaded module can only have one path, which should always be empty ?

Comment: you can put  `path: ''` for  the all lazyloaded module and then set additional routes like `search` in the child route

Comment: @OleEHDufour here is a sample angular app with simple routing ( not lazyloaded though  ) may help you get a picture of your issue : https://github.com/JOELJOSEPHCHALAKUDY/angular-github-user-info-demo/tree/master/src

Comment: @JoelJoseph thanks! Will look into that. I realized that my issue might have nothing to do with the 'lazy' part of routing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Normally, you'd have your routes in your main router module look something like this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'crud',
    loadChildren: () => import('./crudFeatureModule/crud.module').then(mod => mod.CrudModule)
  }
];
```

and call `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`.

Then, in your CrudModule, you would have:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'add', component: AddComponent },
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: 'importer', component: ImporterComponent },
  { path: 'publier', component: PublierComponent }
];
```

and call `RouterModule.forChild(routes)`.

Your URLs would then be `/crud/add`, `/crud/search` etc.

When you use `loadChildren`, the module you lazily load needs to know how to load child routes, i.e. it needs to register its routes to the `RouterModule`. Get what I mean?

P.S. It's generally considered best practice to stick to one language when building routes. Je présume par le nom des routes que tu es francophone :-) généralement on évite de mélanger français et anglais si possible ^^

Comment: I was overlooking the possibilty of using multiple segments in my routes. I will try that and I guess that you answered my question!

Comment: Don't forget to set up routing in BOTH your AppModule AND the lazily loaded module. Only call `RouterModule.forRoot()` in your AppModule, and then `RouterModule.forChild()` in each lazily loaded module. That way, all routes are registered correctly.

Comment: I will! Thanks for your effort and your time.

Comment: @WillAlexander thanks, your ans was of great help, just that I am facing one issue,
when trying to directly access child route say `/crud/add` its not loading anything but giving error, can you plz help, thanks

Comment: @WillAlexander well my routes are actually `segments`, `segments/create` etc.. so when going from `segments` to `segments/create` its working fine but when trying to refresh the same its trying to get assets from `segments` hence errors like
`GET http://localhost:4200/segments/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: That looks like a redirection issue. You're getting that error with `ng serve`?

Comment: yeah with ng serve, but I managed to fix it, my `base-href` was set as `./`, changed it to `/` and its working now, Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Happy to help! Can I suggest that you post your solution as an answer so that others with the same problem can find it easily?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load each component separated in own page you have to create module for each component it depends on you.

I implementing my application's routing like blow and this working

```
  { path: 'person', loadChildren: './projects/person/person.module#PersonModule' },
```

Comment: I just want to avoid creating one module per component ;-)